# Get company name when adding new address

Tags: magento-1.7, forms, address, shipping-address

I am trying to fill in the field: Company, when adding a new address, retrieving the company name from the current address.

I am editing:
/www.vadotex.biz/web/app/design/frontend/vadotex/default/template/customer/address/edit.phtml

and have tried:

```
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getShippingAddress()->getCompany()) ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getAddresses()->getCompany()) ?>
```

as value of the field.

I want it to copy the company name of the current shipping address, but when using above codes, it wont show me any value, and just cuts off the form.

Answer (score 4):

Try `->getPrimaryShippingAddress()` or `->getPrimaryBillingAddress()` on the `getCustomer()` and use ->getCompany()` for the data

Answer (score 1):

In that block (`Mage_Customer_Block_Address_Edit`), you need to do `$this->getAddress()->getCompany()`.

If you do `$this->getCustomer()`, you're getting the customer object, from which you can get addresses a well, but `getAddresses()` or `getShippingAddress()` are not valid methods of the customer object. See `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` you want to retrieve addresses from this object.

Comment: I have tried your answer, but this gives me no value in the field, while i do have the company name filled in my current address.